# How can I target a nested directory in .prettierignore?

Tags: formatting, glob, prettier

I would like to write a `.prettierignore` file to target the files in a single directory, which is nested one level down from the root of the project. I figure the most elegant way to accomplish this is to use a negated pattern to ignore everything but the target directory.

So, I currently have this:

```
# Ignore all
/*
# but for /views
!src/views/
```

Running the `npx prettier --write .` command with that pattern (or similar variations) appears to match no files, and no files change. However, if I run the command without`/views` in the pattern, i.e. just `!src`, then prettier formats everything in the `src` directory, including all the files in `/views`.

What am I missing that I can't successfully target only the nested `/views` directory?

Answer (score -1):

After some more searching, I found this solution, which accomplishes the outcome I was seeking, though, I don't quite understand how it works.

```
#ignore all
/*
#but don't ignore files or directories at root called src
!/src
#ignore everything in src dir?
/src/*
#but don't ignore views dir in src?
!/src/views
```

Why would that be necessary compared to just `src/views`?

Comment: The Prettier code may (or may not) have borrowed the Git search algorithm. This is still just a question about Prettier, though. You can *make* it a Git question but then it's already answered repeatedly ([search for "un-ignore nested"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+un-ignore+nested), for instance).